# Put all elements with specific fisrt character in first positions of an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a folder with photos which need to be displayed on a page.
I read all the photos in an array and then I sort them by date.

I need, after sorting them by date, to put all the photos with the first character '_' at the top of the array. In this way they will be displayed first on the page.

I don't want to use another `foreach` because the execution time is too long.
How can I do this?

```php
$files = (glob("../catalog-reseller/".$actualcat."/*.jpg")); 
usort($files, create_function('$a,$b', 'return filemtime($b) - filemtime($a);'));
foreach (array_slice($files, $nr) as $filename) 
{
    $x=$x+1;
    $pieces = explode('/', $filename);
    $cutname = implode('/', array_slice($pieces, 4, 5));
    $cutname=substr($cutname, 0,-4);
    echo'
        <a href="'.$filename.'" data-rel="lightcase:gallery" title="'.$cutname.'">
            <img src="'.$filename.'" alt="">
        </a>';
    if($x==50){break;}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply integrate that into your `usort` call:

```
usort($files, function ($a, $b) {
    $bsa = basename($a);
    $bsb = basename($b);
    if ($bsa[0] == '_' && $bsb[0] != '_') // a starts with _ but b doesn't
        return -1;
    else if ($bsa[0] != '_' && $bsb[0] == '_') // b starts with _ but a doesn't
        return 1;
    else // both start with _ or both don't
        return (filemtime($b) - filemtime($a));
});
```